# Accessing Objects from a 2d Arraylist of Custom Objects in Java

Tags: java, generics, arraylist, multidimensional-array

Consider the following case. I have 2 classes as shown below:

```
public class CustomObject{

  public int a;
  public String xyz;
  public ArrayList<Integer> arrInt;
  public SomeOtherClass objectSOC;

   public CustomObject(){
   //Constructor
        }
  /*Followed by other methods in the class*/

  }
```

Now there is another class in which I have created ArrayList[][] of CustomObject, the way shown below

```
public class CustomObjectUtil{

 ArrayList<CustomObject>[][] arrCO = new ArrayList[100][100];

 public CustomObjectUtil(){
 //Assume there is an object of CustomObject class, let's call it ObjectCO, and a method that adds values to the arrCO using arrCO[i][j].add(ObjectCO);

 //Now, here I want to access objects from my 2D ArrayList as
   String stringCO = arrCO[indx][indy].xyz;
   ArrayList<Integer> arrIntCO = arrCO[indx][indy].arrInt;
   SomeOtherClass objectSOC_CO = arrCO[indx][indy].objectSOC;
 // But the above method is not allowed;
      }

 }
```

I could not find a way to do this type of assignment. Please comment if you need more info!

Comment: `new ArrayList[100][100]` ???

Comment: @ANS It's a multidimensional array of `ArrayList`. It compiles.

Comment: @VinceEmigh It does not compile fine. It compiles with warnings.

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline I didn't say *fine*, I just said it compiles, as in "*the grammar allows it*".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Object referenced by arrCO[indx][indy] is an  ArrayList

arrCO is a 2-D array of List of CustomObject

do this to access what you're trying to access:

```
List<CustomObject> customObjList = arrCO[indx][indy];
CustomObject customObj = customObjList.get(0)  // assuming there are elements in this list
```

Now you can access arrInt & objectSOC as

```
customObj.arrInt & customObj.objectSOC
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was interpreting the declaration itself in a faulty manner.
Just to add to it a bit, if anyone wants to further visualise it a bit in their head, viewing variable in Debugger mode in any IDE, NetBeans/Eclipse might help!